# Type 3 compensator design

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I'm about to simulate a voltage mode buck-boost converter. To stabilize this converter, it is well known that we should use a type 3 compensator. The configuration of that compensator is given below with the components values computed in matlab with the following specifications:

- The switching frequency is 100kHz.
- DC Bias (Output voltage from power stage to error amplifier) is 12V
- We place a double zero at 600Hz
- A first pole at 7kHz
- A second pole at 50kHz

The circuit I have simulated is shown below:

[image]

When I simulate the transfer function of a type 3 compensator in matlab, I get the bode plot in the figure below (as expected):

[image]

But when i simulate the circuit in Simetrix/Simplis, I get something different and has nothing to do with the well known frequency response of Type 3 amplifier
The frequency response I got is shown below:

[image]

If we compare what I got in matlab and Simetrix/Simplis simulator we notice a huge difference between the two. I have changed many parameters, like the gain of the error amplifier but I did not get the expected response of a type 3 amplifier!
Could anyone help me to figure out what may be the problem ?

Comment: On top of a potential bias problem, you've swapped Verr and Vac in your Bode box: Verr is the output while Vac is the input.

Answer (score 1):

The op-amp must be biased so that it does not rail up or down. It means the 12-V source should not be 12 V but slightly less or more, depending on the open-loop gain of the op-amp. You can easily add an auto-bias circuit as shown in the below template:

[image]

You set the op-amp output to 2.5 V for instance (far from the min or the max output) and the E1 source auto-biases the divider network, ensuring a correct operation in the linear zone of the op-amp.

Comment: But when I probe the OP AMP at the inverting input I got 2.49v, which meas the op amp is biased, right ? and what made me to think in that way, is that Simplis simulator can provide an AC response from a transient circuit

Comment: As I said in the comment section, it seems that you have swapped the input and output of the Bode box.